# php execute code before every function call

Tags: php, hook

I want to introduce heartbeats to some of my scripts.
I have therefore added a service class that allows to save and update a timestamp in the DB.
It also keeps track of the last hearbeat and only queries the DB every 10s to prevent excessive DB calls.

Currently I need to manually add the heartbeat function call throughout my whole codebase.

Is there some way run it regularly automatically.

I found this that could be going into the right direction:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-set-hook.php

However this requires zend and to install an extension.

Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: It's used for unit testing, not recommended in production

Comment: I don't see what your objective is.  The default concept of html pages is that they are stateless.  So, how is the second invocation know anything about the previous one.  Not just the tick count, but also the data from the database. Where are you going to store this so that the data is preserved across page boundary and across the users ?

Comment: @RohitGupta this has nothing to do with html pages. It's a php script and I want to perform some action at each function call.

Answer (score 0):

A function like that should really only be used in DEV, never in prod, because it will be a massive impact on execution times.

I think you are searching for something like [`register_tick_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php).

I'll not drop a code example here, because the PHP docs do contain good ones.